# Translate English Text to Hindi in Android

Tags: android, translate, hindi

I want to convert a text in English to Hindi and display it in the TextView.I followed the following URL http://android-er.blogspot.com/2009/10/androidtranslate-using-google-translate.html but it dosen't seems to work.
Is there any other method to do it?Help me out.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.read_view);
    mTts = new TextToSpeech(this,this);
    try {
        setTranslate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void setTranslate() throws Exception {
 String OutputString = Translate.execute("hello",
         Language.ENGLISH, Language.HINDI);
 TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.translate);
 tv.setText(OutputString);
}
```

Here I am trying to display hindi text in the TextView id "translate"

Comment: You have to give a bit more info. Can you show us your code?

Comment: Please note that the Google Translate API has been deprecated and will be turned off by year's end.

Comment: Is there any other way , I can dispaly the user a Hindi Text?I am debugging on Samsung Android 2.2

Answer (score 0):

make sure your application does have [internet permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET)

```
android.permission.INTERNET
```

add google translate api jar i.e google.api.translate-java-0.90.jar

Also check this [client api](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/) it comes useful some times when u want to handle certain events and requests with ease

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Bing Translator offers a translator for this english-hindi and its completely free for a limited searches. 
    http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/using-the-free-bing-translation-apis.